# CSS: modal dialog with fixed header, footer and scrollable content

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

Trying to style a fake modal dialog so that the essential navigation and action buttons (i.e. save, close) are always available to the user no matter the browser size. This means fixing a header and a footer in place but making the content scroll.

Getting the header in place is easy enough, but I'm having problems with the other requirements, namely:

- The content is currently in a fliud two-column layout. Setting its container to be scrollable (i.e. overflow: auto) perhaps unsurprisingly causes it to revert to a single column to fill all the space. Is there an easy fix for this? Put another wrapper round the container and making that scrollable for instance?
- I cannot work out how to get the footer to fix to the bottom of the *modal* I can fix it to the bottom of the *page* easily enough, but no matter what I do with position, display and overflow, I can't get it to stay inside the modal container.

Any suggestions gratefully received. I'm already in stylesheet hell, so I'm a bit reluctant to post what I've already got - but will if necessary.

EDIT - code requested. This is what I've got before trying to fix the footer and scroll the content. Here goes:

First, the modal container:

```
.dialog-outer {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #C1C1C1;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    max-height: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Header:

```
.dialog-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Navigation (sits under the header before the main content):

```
.dialog-navigation {
    height: 32px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

main content

```
.dialog-maincolumn {
    float: left;
}
```

left/right column split inside maincolumn:

```
.dialog-contentblock {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

footer:

```
.dialog-actions {
    clear: both;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: How abt posting some code?